# Record a Web radio stream Using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, stream, streaming

I need to get the data from an internet radio stream that I play with Qt and its QMediaplayer Class like so :

```
player->setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl("http://rfm-live-mp3-64.scdn.arkena.com/rfm.mp3")),
```

but I cannot figure out how to access the stream data and record it to a buffer or a file. I tried QAUdioRecorder but the audioIn available seems only to be the mic.

Does anyone know if this is possible with Qt?

Thanks!

Edit----------------------
Here is the code with the suggestion of eyllanesc :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

QFile file(R"(D:\\Mes_Projets_Qt_Creator\\build-TestQtDesignWidget- 
Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\\ML.wav)");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray arr = file.readAll();


QBuffer *buffer = new QBuffer(player); 
buffer->setData(arr);
buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);


QFile autreFile("hello.wav");
autreFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&autreFile);
out << arr;

QAudioFormat format; 
format.setSampleRate(22050);
format.setChannelCount(1);
format.setSampleSize(16);
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
qWarning() << "Raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play 
audio.";
return;
}

QAudioOutput* audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(format, this);
audioOutput->start(buffer);

foreach (const QAudioDeviceInfo &deviceInfo, 
QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput))
qDebug() << "Device name: " << deviceInfo.deviceName();

    QNetworkAccessManager nam;

QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://rfm-live-mp3- 
64.scdn.arkena.com/rfm.mp3"));

QString downloadDir = 
QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation);

QFile file2(QDir(downloadDir).absoluteFilePath("test.mp3"));

QDataStream ds(&file2);

if(!file2.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
   //return -1; 



QNetworkReply *reply = nam.get(request);
QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, [reply, &ds] 
(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal){
    ds << reply->readAll();
    qDebug()<<bytesReceived<<bytesTotal;
});

qDebug()<<reply;
```

Comment: I tried to set it up today I figured it was in the slot but I couldn't manage to set things right ; I just see your edit and details : thanks for the time you took to make this exemple. I finally copy paste it : It works just great !            Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you can use `QNetworkAccessManager` to download the file as I show below:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QDir>
#include <QFile>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QStandardPaths>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QNetworkAccessManager nam;

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://rfm-live-mp3-64.scdn.arkena.com/rfm.mp3"));

    QString downloadDir = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation);

    QFile file(QDir(downloadDir).absoluteFilePath("test.mp3"));

    QDataStream ds(&file);

    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
        return -1;

    QNetworkReply *reply = nam.get(request);
    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, [reply, &ds](qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal){
        ds << reply->readAll();
        qDebug()<<bytesReceived<<bytesTotal;
    });

    qDebug()<<reply;

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

Update:

In the following example I show how to implement my solution in a GUI, for this I have built the following interface using Qt Designer:

[image]

[image]

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QFile>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void onDownloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal);

    void on_selectButton_clicked();

    void on_startButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QNetworkAccessManager mNam;
    QFile mFile;
    QDataStream mDs;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDir>
#include <QFile>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QLineEdit>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->leUrl->setText("http://rfm-live-mp3-64.scdn.arkena.com/rfm.mp3");
    ui->leOutput->setText(QDir(qApp->applicationDirPath()).absoluteFilePath("test.mp3"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::onDownloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)
{
        mDs << reply->readAll();
    qDebug()<<bytesReceived<< bytesTotal;
}

void MainWindow::on_selectButton_clicked()
{
    QString filename =QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Select ", qApp->applicationDirPath());
    ui->leOutput->setText(filename);
}

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{

    mFile.setFileName(ui->leOutput->text());

    mDs.setDevice(&mFile);

    if(!mFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
        return;

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(ui->leUrl->text()));

    reply = mNam.get(request);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this, &MainWindow::onDownloadProgress);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(reply){
        reply->disconnect(SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
        reply->abort();
        mFile.close();
        reply->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/50764406/50764406-GUI).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply it looks perfect 'but' this is where I show my beginner skill : I cannot compile it the "reply" inside the connect returns :D:\[...]\mainwindow.cpp:110: erreur : 'reply' was not declared in this scope
     QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, [reply, &ds](qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal){     I tried to work it out but I don't really know how to do. 
                      ^

Comment: @l_-A-_l 
Have you added `QT += network` in the .pro?

Comment: Now I have, and stil I get the same

Comment: Make sure you have `QNetworkReply *reply;` in the private section of your mainwindow.h file.

Comment: @NicholasJohnson I do not understand your comment, explain yourself better.

Comment: I'm talking to @l_-A-_l

Comment: @NicholasJohnson 
You should do it below the question or at least use `@l_-A-_l`

Comment: @Nicolas Hi , yes it's done and it works great now. Thanks to both of you !

Comment: I'd have a further question: There's a part of the code I didn't post here where I tried to get the stream from a`player->mediaStream()`is it possible or not ?